# Find and replace numbers between ( and ,

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have been trying to put together a regex that would find and replace numbers between `(` and `,` with just space. Example:

```
INSERT [dbo].[table] ([col], [col], [col]) VALUES (30, N'SFTP', 15, 1)
```

Would be transformed to:

```
INSERT [dbo].[table] ([col], [col], [col]) VALUES (N'SFTP', 15, 1)
```

30 would be removed from the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
\(\d+,\s*
```

with

```
\(
```

`\d+` will match numbers with any length

Comment: This worked perfectly!